# How can i change the date format for "list-month view" in full calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I just want to change the date format for list month view('fc-list-heading-main') in full calendar. I tried all different way but i was not successful. Please let me know how can i change date format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

After going through the source code (*fullcalendar.js*) I have found the solution: there is an option called `listDayFormat`. So try something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'listMonth',
    listDayFormat: 'D MMMM YYYY'
});
```

This will change the date format for `fc-list-heading-main`.
There is also an alternative formatting option called `listDayAltFormat`, that one is responsible for the formatting inside `fc-list-heading-alt`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now i didn't find any solution for this. I didn't find any full calendar api for this. I have fixed this with jQuery.

```
jQuery('.fc-list-table .fc-list-heading').each(function () {
       jQuery(this).find(".fc-list-heading-main").html(jQuery(this).find(".fc-list-heading-main").text().split(',')[0].split(' ')[1]);
     });
     jQuery('.fc-list-table .fc-list-heading').each(function () {
       jQuery(this).find(".fc-list-heading-alt").html(jQuery(this).find(".fc-list-heading-alt").text().slice(0, 3));
     });
```

Placed the above code after calendar rendered. Also added this code for next and previous events.